# something wrong with table in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

```
package Controller;

import Play.Play;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.StretchViewport;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport;
import com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame;
import player.Player;

public class Controller {
    Viewport viewport;
    MyGdxGame game;
    Stage stage;
    World world;
    public boolean rightpressed,leftpressed;
    OrthographicCamera cam;
    public void Controllermaker(){
        game=new MyGdxGame();
        cam=new OrthographicCamera(MyGdxGame.width/100,MyGdxGame.hight/100);
        viewport=new StretchViewport(MyGdxGame.width/100,MyGdxGame.hight/100,cam);
        stage=new Stage(viewport,MyGdxGame.batch);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);


        Image image=new Image(new Texture("img2.png"));
        Table table=new Table();
        table.left().bottom();
        image.setSize(image.getImageWidth(),image.getHeight());
        table.add();
        table.add(image).size(1,1);
        table.add();
        table.row().pad(5);


        image.addListener(new InputListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                rightpressed=true;
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                rightpressed=false;
            }
        });
        Image image1=new Image(new Texture("arrow_keys.png"));
        table.add();
        table.add(image1).size(1,1);
        table.add();
        table.row().pad(5);
        image1.addListener(new InputListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                rightpressed=true;
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                rightpressed=false;
            }
        });

        stage.addActor(table);
        stage.act();
        stage.draw();
    }`
```

I have no idea what's wrong with this code but when I add the second image (imge1), both images do not show but when I start it with one image it works not perfectly because when I change the size of the table for less than 0.5 the image disappears but otherwise I can only add one image to this table and the image shows.

Comment: On this row: table.add(image1).size(1,1); you set the cell size to 1x1 pixel is that actually what you want? What happens if you remove the size attribute? If you enable debugging on the table (by adding table.debug();) What do you see?

Comment: no i want it to be size(0.3f,0.3f) but when i do that it does not show up 

and i added debug still same problem

Comment: When using size() you are setting the size in pixels. If you want to scale the image to 0.3 times the original size you need to multiply the original size by 0.3. So something like: table.add(image).size(image.getMingWidth() * 0.3f, image.getMingHeight() * 0.3f);

Comment: There's also a setScaling on the image itself you could try: image.setScaling(0.3f);